# Cut zeros from the end of the list

Tags: python, list, python-3.x

function receives in argument list that have a lot of `0` at the end like:

```
[48, 39, 23, 15, 11, 12, 5, 9, 7, 3, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[137, 30, 12, 3, 1, 0, 0, 0]
```

If length of the list and the number of zeros at the end are always different, how can I trim it from zeroes to get

```
[48, 39, 23, 15, 11, 12, 5, 9, 7, 3, 4, 2, 0, 0, 1, 0 , 1]
[137, 30, 12, 3, 1]
```

Comment: none of the current answers except [mine](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28805512/4279) produce correct values if input can be an empty list or if there is no trailing zeros in the list or if `None` could be in the list.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
list1 = [48, 39, 23, 15, 11, 12, 5, 9, 7, 3, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
list2 = [137, 30, 12, 3, 1, 0, 0, 0]


def pop_zeros(items):
    while items[-1] == 0:
        items.pop()

pop_zeros(list1)
pop_zeros(list2)
print(list1)
print(list2)
```

Output

```
[48, 39, 23, 15, 11, 12, 5, 9, 7, 3, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1]
[137, 30, 12, 3, 1]
```

Comment: thank you, but I thought that with all of this 'batteries are included' comes some `list.trim(0)`

Comment: @qm69: For strings, Python can trim leading or trailing values. You have a list. It would be trivial to write a `list.rtrim(0)` method if you wish.

Comment: it breaks if `len(items) == 0`. It is 2x slower than [`del lst[-i:]` solution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28805512/4279).

Answer (score 4):

The most efficient way if to use reversed and delete, pop is usually used when you want to use the element you pop off:

```
def remove_zeros(l):
    for ele in reversed(l):
        if not ele:
            del l[-1]
        else:
            break
```

Some timings using python2.7:

```
In [15]: %%timeit 
li = [48, 39, 23, 15, 11, 12, 5, 9, 7, 3, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0] + [0 for _ in range(1000)]
li[:]=li[0:-len(list(it.takewhile(lambda x: x==0, reversed(li))))]
   ....: 
10000 loops, best of 3: 170 µs per loop

In [16]: %%timeit
l = [48, 39, 23, 15, 11, 12, 5, 9, 7, 3, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0] + [0 for _ in range(1000)]
remove_zeros(l)
   ....: 
10000 loops, best of 3: 103 µs per loop

In [18]: %%timeit
l = [48, 39, 23, 15, 11, 12, 5, 9, 7, 3, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0] + [0 for _ in range(1000)]
pop_zeros(l)
   ....: 
10000 loops, best of 3: 160 µs per loop
```

If you are like the idea of a trim method you can use [numpy.trim_zeros](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.trim_zeros.html):

```
import numpy as np

lst = [48, 39, 23, 15, 11, 12, 5, 9, 7, 3, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
lst[:] = np.trim_zeros(lst)
lst
[48, 39, 23, 15, 11, 12, 5, 9, 7, 3, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1]


In [10]: %%timeit 
lst = [48, 39, 23, 15, 11, 12, 5, 9, 7, 3, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0] + [0 for _ in range(1000)]
lst[:] = np.trim_zeros(lst)
   ....: 
10000 loops, best of 3: 150 µs per loop
```

Timings using python3.4 and using `ele == 0` to avoid removing other potential falsey values if the list contains anything other than numbers:

```
In [10]: %%timeit
l = [48, 39, 23, 15, 11, 12, 5, 9, 7, 3, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0] + [0 for _ in range(1000)]
pop_zeros(l)
   ....: 
1000 loops, best of 3: 202 µs per loop

In [11]: %%timeit
l = [48, 39, 23, 15, 11, 12, 5, 9, 7, 3, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0] + [0 for _ in range(1000)]
remove_zeros(l)
   ....: 
10000 loops, best of 3: 131 µs per loop
In [12]: %%timeit
li = [48, 39, 23, 15, 11, 12, 5, 9, 7, 3, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0] + [0 for _ in range(1000)]
li[:]=li[0:-len(list(it.takewhile(lambda x: x==0, reversed(li))))]
   ...: 
1000 loops, best of 3: 217 µs per loop
```

Comment: The computational complexity of pop and del on Python lists are the same for items at the end.

Comment: @dawg,  of course the complexity is the same, this is just more efficient. If you don't agree time it.

Comment: I like the timing. Note: `if not ele:` is not the same as `if not ele==0:` It may be that `None` is a legit list entry that is not to be trimmed. This may change the timing as well. Cheers

Comment: @dawg,  added python3 timings using `== 0` and retested earlier using `== 0 `,the updated timings are , `165 µs per loop`,`117 µs per loop`,`163 µs per loop` in same order as original.

Comment: it breaks if there is `None` value in the list. It is slower than [`del lst[-i:]` solution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28805512/4279).

Answer (score 2):

you can pop elements in a while loop and break the loop if the `element != 0`

```
while mylist:
    if mylist[-1] != 0:
        break
    del mylist[-1]
```

alternatively, iterate through the list in reverse and <s>slice</s> delete in bulk:

```
for i, j in enumerate(reversed(mylist)):
    if j != 0 and i == 0:
        break
    elif j != 0:
        del mylist[-i:]
        break
```

*edit*: in a previous version, I proposed `mylist = mylist[0:-i]` instead of `del mylist[-i:]`. The first statement slices & copies the list to a new variable, while the latter modifies the list in place. The latter is more efficient.

Comment: thanks for the comment @J.F.Sebastian. updated answer to handle case where last element is non-zero.

Answer (score 2):

Another way using [itertools takewhile](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.takewhile) and slice assignment:

```
>>> li=[48, 39, 23, 15, 11, 12, 5, 9, 7, 3, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
>>> import itertools as it
>>> li[:]=li[0:-len(list(it.takewhile(lambda x: x==0, reversed(li))))]
>>> li
[48, 39, 23, 15, 11, 12, 5, 9, 7, 3, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1]
```

Comment: it breaks if there is no trailing zeros.

Answer (score 0):

You can use numpy for this.

```py
>> import numpy as np
>> a = [1,1,1,3,4,0,4,4,0,0]
>> np.trim_zeroes(a,'b')
[0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 3, 4, 0, 4, 4]
```

Check out the documentation https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.trim_zeros.html

Answer (score -1):

```
def rstrip(lst, value):
    for i, x in enumerate(reversed(lst)):
        if x != value:
           if i:
              del lst[-i:]
           return
```

`del lst[-i:]` might be more efficient than multiple `lst.pop()`:

```
$ python -mtimeit -s 'from list_rstrip import rstrip, zpop; L=[0]*'1000000 'M=L[:]; rstrip(M, 0)'
10 loops, best of 3: 55.2 msec per loop
$ python -mtimeit -s 'from list_rstrip import rstrip, zpop; L=[0]*'1000000 'M=L[:]; zpop(M)'
10 loops, best of 3: 133 msec per loop
$ python -mtimeit -s 'from list_rstrip import remove_zeros; L=[0]*'1000000 'M=L[:]; remove_zeros(M)'
10 loops, best of 3: 81.4 msec per loop
```

where `zpop()`:

```
def zpop(lst):
    while lst and lst[-1] == 0:
        lst.pop()
```

Comment: why would somebody downvote an answer that was the only correct answer at the time of its posting.

Comment: Why? I am new here, but I guess it could be a response to your "promotional" comments on several other questions like "...none of the current answers except mine...". 

Possibly some user has "abused" the voting, to send you an anonymous message? I am not taking a position here, but I am writing this comment because I noticed your input as something special.

I suppose that an answer (code) which is stable against potential "exotic data", even if not mentioned by the OP, could be a bonus. And speed certainly is helpful for certain contexts - and not an issue in others.

hth

Comment: @MartinZaske: thank you. I don't mind a rage-vote. I asked in case I missed something obvious in the answer (it happens).

Comment: fine. Now I even learnt a new term "rage-vote"... Still I am enjoying Stackoverflow a lot; very calm, very results-focused. I am learning all the time, from good and bad contributions. (Welcome to delete this soon. Could not find a feature to just contact another user.) Have searched and cannot find how to make @callouts, sorry.